# How to call Matlab's Toolbar Event Handlers

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

When using Guide in Matlab to create a GUI with a toolbar, you have the option to use predefined toolbar elements, e.g. open file, zoom in and out...
You drag and drop those into your GUI and when you click on one of their icons some auto-generated callback is executed. 
Is there a way to execute these auto-generated callbacks from your code yourself? I would like to include some of the functionality provided by these toolbar elements within the GUI menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a custom tag to the toolbar item in the "Tool Properties" section. This tag name indicates the field within the `handles` struct that contains the handle to the toolbar tool.

[image]

You can then get the assigned callback via the [`ClickedCallback`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipushtool-properties.html#property_ClickedCallback) property,  and then execute the callback programmatically using [`hgfeval`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hgfeval)

```
function mycallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    cback = get(handles.mypushtool, 'ClickedCallback');
    hgfeval(cback)
end
```

If you want to simply copy the callback to your menu, you can modify your `OpeningFcn` so that you just copy the `ClickedCallback` property of the tool to the menu

```
function myGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    set(handles.mymenuitem, 'Callback', get(handles.mytoolbaritem, 'ClickedCallback'));
end
```